# How do you understand this Rashi? (Bamidbor, 15:24)

Tags: parashat-shelach

In Parsha Shelach, 6th reading, verse 24:

> וְהָיָ֗ה אִ֣ם מֵֽעֵינֵ֣י הָֽעֵדָה֘ נֶֽעֶשְׂתָ֣ה לִשְׁגָגָה֒

And Rashi explaines it to mean that the Rabbis ruled concerning one form of service, that it was permitted to worship an idol in this manner.

> אם מעיני העדה נעשתה עבירה זו ע"י שוגג, כגון ששגגו והורו על אחת מן
> העבודות שהיא מותרת לעבוד עבודה זרה בכך

Since when would the rabbis permit worship of idols **in any manner**?! The way Rashi words it, it sounds like there are some forms of idol worship that are okay!

What would be a scenario that the verse is speaking about?

Answer (score 5):

*Since when would the rabbis permit worship of idols in any manner?*

Obviously they shouldn't but since they were human they were capable of making a mistake about whether something falls into the category of Avodah Zora or not.

The Mishna in Horayos 1:3  says if Beis Din makes a mistake as big as  saying there is no Averia of Avodah Zora then they would not bring a Korbon .It is so wrong that it isn't even considered a Psak of a Beis Din.What Rabbi would permit such a thing?

If however  they make the mistake of saying there is an Aveira of Avodah Zora but (certain types) of bowing to it **is not included in what the Torah means** when it prohibits Avoda Zora they would bring  the Korbon. Such a mistake is possible for a human Beis Din to make.

See  Horayas 4A for  further discussion of the above

Comment: To add on to this excellent answer: The concept in question is not limited to idolatry and is discussed further back in Parshas Vayikra. What’s unique about idolatry is that there’s a special Karban for it, different from a similar type of ruling on any other Aveira in the Torah.

Comment: Why would the rabbis say that certain types of bowing to idols is permissible? That doesn't make sense! I can serve idols in some ways but not in other ways? So serving idols is permissible! (In some ways)

Comment: They would only be saying certain types of bowing to idols is permissible if they (incorrectly) don't consider it to be idol worship.(eg indirect bowing) They would never say it is permissible if they considered it to be idol worship or that there are types of permissible idol worship.

Answer (score 1):

**Rambam Hilchot Avodah Zarah 3:1**

> עבודות הרבה קבעו עובדי כוכבים לכל צלם וצלם ולכל צורה וצורה ועבודת זה אינה כעבודת זה כגון פעור שעבודתו שפוער אדם עצמו לו ומרקוליס שעבודתו שיזרוק לו אבנים או יסקל מלפניו אבנים והרבה עבודות כגון אלו תקנו לשאר צלמים, לפיכך הפוער עצמו למרקוליס או שזרק אבן לפעור פטור עד שיעבוד אותו דרך עבודתו שנאמר איכה יעבדו הגוים האלה את אלהיהם ואעשה כן גם אני, ומפני זה הענין צריכין בית דין לידע דרכי העבודות שאין סוקלין עובד כוכבים עד שידעו שזו היא דרך עבודתו
>
> The gentiles established various different services for each particular idol and image. These services do not [necessarily] resemble each other. For example, Pe'or is served by defecating before it. Marculis is served by throwing stones at it or clearing stones away from it. Similarly, other services were instituted for other idols.
>
> One who defecates before Marculis or throws a stone at Pe'or is free of liability until he serves it according to the accepted modes of service, as [implied by Deuteronomy 12:30]: "[Lest one inquire about their gods, saying,] 'How did these nations serve their gods? I will do the same.'"
>
> For this reason, a court must know the types of worship [practiced by gentiles], because an idolater is stoned to death only when we know that [he has worshiped a false god] in the mode in which it is traditionally worshiped.
>
> (Touger translation)

Thus a court could mistakenly rule that a certain form of worship is not the correct mode of worship for a particular idol.

Comment: But presumably this would be *patur aval asur* rather than *mutar*?

Comment: @JoelK Why, necessarily? Say they said it's permissible to throw stones at Merculis, not realizing that it's the standard mode of worshipping it. If it were any other idol, which in fact isn't worshipped that way, wouldn't it be quite permissible to throw stones at it?

Comment: so it's possible for someone to serve idols with the intent of serving idols, but if it's not in the manner that is regularly done, then it's not a sin? what about if someone makes his own idol that no one else worships and worships it in his own way?